# Trying to create vectors in R but they are always 'integers'?

Tags: r, vector

I don't know what i'm doing wrong. These are the different ways I tried creating the vectors:

```
indeces = (1:n)
indeces <- c(1:n)
```

But I can't apply functions to indeces that works for vectors for either of those definitions, and using typeof() tells me that it's an integer? Shouldn't it be a vector?

Comment: indeces the name of the object you craete. This object is a vector in which you store integer values form 1 to n. So everything seems correct.

Comment: _Everything in R is a vector._  There are no scalars.  When you assign `mypi <- 3.14` you created a vector of length one.  Check a decent text on R for more.  See my answer for more.

Comment: So then why would I not be able to use sample(ideces,10)? The error says invalid first arguemt, which I took as meaning that indeces is not the right type of object.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a little from the comment I just made: *Everything in R is a vector*. There are no scalars.

When you assign mypi <- 3.14 you created a vector of length one. But `is.vector()` is true!

```
> mypi <- 3.14
> class(mypi)
[1] "numeric"
> storage.mode(mypi)
[1] "double"
> length(mypi)
[1] 1
> is.vector(mypi)
[1] TRUE
>
```

Comment: So then why would I not be able to use sample(ideces,10)? The error says invalid first arguemt, which I took as meaning that indeces is not the right type of object.

Comment: a) This has nothing to do with your previous question. b) Read `help(sample)`, maybe `replace=TRUE` was what you missed. `indeces <- 1:5; sample(indeces, 10, TRUE)` works perfectly fine.  Again, maybe time for an introductory text on R?  There are many available, including a few free ones. Good luck!